# I am Writing a program in RStudio to calculate the equilibrium potential and it only outputs Inf

Tags: r

I'm writing a program that automatically calculates the Nernst potential of a given ion in a cell. So, I made the user specify which ion, its charge, and their concentrations inside and outside of the cell. I defined the constants, wrote the equation in R format and all I keep getting as an output is Inf.

Since I'm new to R , I'm pretty sure I have made a mistake somewhere in my code. So, I need your help to revise my code and tell me what I'm doing wrong.

```
readline("Which ion will you use to measure the potential equilibrium? = ")
z<-as.integer(readline("What is the ion charge? = "))
co<-as.integer(readline("¿What is the extracelular concentration of the ion (mM) = "))
ci<-as.integer(readline("¿What is the intracelular concentration of the ion (mM) = "))

#Defining constants

R<-8.3145 # unit J/K.mol
Tbody<-310.15 # K=Cº+273.15; Cº=37º body temperature
Faraday<-96485.337 # unit C/mol Faraday constant

#Equation
Veq<-((R*Tbody)/(z*Faraday))*log((co/ci), base = exp(1))  
Veq_mV<-Veq*1000 # from V to mV

#output
cat("The equilibrium potential for ",ion," is: ",Veq_mV)
```

The type of data I'm using as imput is a string for the first question, and integers for the rest. It works really well with other ions like Na+, Cl-, K+, but with Ca2+ it only outputs Inf. The outside concentration of Ca2+ is 0.0001 to 0.0007 or 0.1 uM / 0.7 uM. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in your code is caused by casting your inputs to integers. Using `as.numeric` instead of `as.integer` will keep the values after any decimal points. `as.integer` will cut off decimals, so a Ca2+ concentration of 0.0001 will be interpreted as 0 with `as.integer` and will lead to a division by 0 error, resulting in an output of `Inf`.

Try this:

```
readline("Which ion will you use to measure the potential equilibrium? = ")
z<-as.numeric(readline("What is the ion charge? = "))
co<-as.numeric(readline("¿What is the extracelular concentration of the ion (mM) = "))
ci<-as.numeric(readline("¿What is the intracelular concentration of the ion (mM) = "))

#Defining constants

R<-8.3145 # unit J/K.mol
Tbody<-310.15 # K=Cº+273.15; Cº=37º body temperature
Faraday<-96485.337 # unit C/mol Faraday constant

#Equation
Veq<-((R*Tbody)/(z*Faraday))*log((co/ci), base = exp(1))  
Veq_mV<-Veq*1000 # from V to mV

#output
cat("The equilibrium potential for ",ion," is: ",Veq_mV)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, I've adjusted the code a bit, including input for Temperature in C and improved the precision of Faraday's constant.

```
# Inputs
Ion <- readline("Which ion will you use to measure the potential equilibrium? = ")
Z <- as.numeric(readline("What is the ion charge? = "))
Co <- as.numeric(readline("What is the extracelular concentration of the ion (mM) = "))
Ci <- as.numeric(readline("What is the intracelular concentration of the ion (mM) = "))
TC <- as.numeric(readline("What is the temperature in Centigrade = "))

# Convert C into K
TState <- (TC + 237.15) # body temp = 37º C (310.15º K)  K=Cº+273.15

#Defining constants

R<-8.3145 # unit J/K.mol
Faraday<-96485.3321233 # unit C/mol Faraday constant

#Equation
Veq<-((R*TState)/(Z*Faraday))*log((Co/Ci), base = exp(1))  
Veq_mV<-Veq*1000 # from V to mV

#output
cat("The equilibrium potential for ",Ion," is: ",Veq_mV)
```